# Why should I use the tag <div> when I can add the id="_" attribute to any other tag in my HTML?

Tags: html

Why should I use the tag  when I can add the id="_" attribute to any other tag in my HTML and then act on it. Thanks! :D

Comment: Can you write an example?

Comment: Do you understand the usage of the various tags? Difference between inline and block level elements? If you want a career in web dev you'll learn when to use what and not just assume an id or class with a coupled css declaration of inline / block is sufficient or semantically correct. If you write psychotic, unreadable code, you'll learn the hard way. Otherwise, standards exist for a reason

Comment: What they said. Also, you can add the `id="_"` attribute to at most one element, no more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use a DIV, in fact, sometimes you shouldn't. Different elements serve different purposes.

You can see what a DIV is for here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div

The HTML5 spec introduced a lot of new semantic elements that replaced a lot of what people used DIVs for. You can read about some of those here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

While you are at it, I recommend you read a little on ID's vs. Classes. When I started out with HTML, I used way too many IDs: https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/